# when require(), it's automatic run console.log of required file - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I'm learning NodeJs and got this question. Why the console.log go though to index.js file even i didn't import it.

I thought that i only de-structuring and take the sum func from modules.js to index.js.

Any explanation or instruction? Thanks a lot.

```
/*modules.js*/
module.exports.sum = (a,b) => a + b

console.log("this is from module");

/*index.js*/
const {sum} = require("./modules")
console.log("sum", ourModules.sum(7,8))

/*bash*/
node index.js
this is from module
sum 15
```

Comment: What do you mean you didn't "import" it ? what do you think is `const {sum} = require("./modules")` ?

Comment: ah yeah, i mean require :D

Comment: Well, you **did** require it.

Comment: May I guess that the question "why is `console.log` available in Node.JS by default"?

Comment: I think OP just thinks if he required a module, than the program will continue executing the required module and **never** return to the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require()` a file/module in Node.js, *all* of the contents of that file are executed.

This means that even though you're exporting `sum = (a,b) => a + b` at the *top* of your `modules.js`, the `console.log()` underneath it will *still* get called because you *are* still requiring it in `index.js`.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Maybe, I will read more about nodejs. 
Cause I used ReactJS before and if { thisVar,thisFunc} , they will only take thisVar,thisFunc instead of taking whole props.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: That's the same kind of import, so the behaviour is the same as in Node (unless your module bundler excludes it). The difference is that props do not show signs of execution (like a `console.log` does), but they are still getting interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Module._load
This function checks whether the module is in the cache already - if so, it returns the exports object.

If the module is native, it calls the NativeModule.require() with the filename and returns the result.

Otherwise, it creates a new module for the file and saves it to the cache. Then it loads the file contents before returning its exports object.

Module._compile
The compile function runs the file contents in the correct scope or sandbox, as well as exposes helper variables like require, module or exports to the file.